# Toggle icon on Jquery button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, button, toggle

I have a JQuery button like this:

```
$("#Activechk").button();

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="Activechk" /><label for="Activechk">Active</label>
```

When the button is "on" or "checked" I want to show icon primary: ui-icon-check and when the button is "off" or "not check" I want to show icon primary: ui-icon-cancel.

How would I do this?

Note: when the page loads the initial value (checked or not checked) of the button is gotten from a value in a database, then the user can click the toggle button and click save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.  Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/387j4/7/) http://jsfiddle.net/387j4/7/

```
function myclickfunction (element) {
     if (element.checked) {
      $(element).button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-check' });
    } else {
      $(element).button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-cancel' });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var activechk = $("#Activechk");
  activechk.button();
  activechk.click(function() {
    myclickfunction (this);
  });

  myclickfunction(activechk[0]);
});
```

Comment: nice, almost perfect, however after the page loads, the first time I click the button nothing happens. After that it works fine.

Comment: Its seems as though it is force the button to be "clicked" rather than just executing the click event

Comment: Replacing activechk.trigger('click'); with this: if ($("#Activechk").checked) {
            $("#Activechk").button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-check' }); works. However if I have checked="checked" property on the checkbox it does not work. The button is checked, but the icon is wrong.
        } else {
            $("#Activechk").button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-cancel' });
        }

Comment: @kralco626 ... can you post a demo to jsfiddle.com

Comment: ohhh you mean jsfiddle.net, sure give me a few

Comment: having trouble adding the jquery librarys, in my code I link to a file, not through the web. Not sure what the web addresses should be for jquery ui

Comment: @kralco626 ...well if you can get a simple demo up somewhere I will have a look.

Comment: @kralco626.. Hey I edited my answer and posted a demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/387j4/7/

Comment: However when there is more than one button, when you click back and forth between the two sometimes the icon does not change/ the icon changes and the selection does not. http://jsfiddle.net/387j4/10/ If you click around between the two buttons you can get it so that one of the buttons is gray but has a check or is white but has a cancel icon, any ideas? This is particularly true if you click quickly, or move the mouse off the button as clicking... whats going on?